# Highcharts pie/variablepie align multilines label on plotedge

Tags: highcharts, label, alignment, pie-chart

I use variable pie with some long and multi-lines labels (label 
 value1 
 value 2).
To optimize the rendering of the chart, I use the alignTo "plotEdges" option and it's working well but it seems it cannot align on the plot edge all the lines of the labels.
My options are :

```
dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        alignTo: "plotEdges",
        formatter: function () { return "<b>"+this.point.name+"</b><br><i>"+""+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 0, ".", " ")+" </i> <i>("+Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y/11999*100), 2, ".", " ")+"%)</i><br><i>"+""+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.z, 0, ".", " ")+" </i>";}},
    innerSize: "20%",
}
```

You can see the result here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/95ochyqz/

I would like all labels on the right of the chart right aligned (values right aligned under the title of the label).
The labels on the left of the chart are correctly left aligned near the plotEdge.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the `dataLabels.useHTML` to true to render them as outstanding elements,
2. In the `dataLabels.formatter` callback check the label alignment and add a float styling for the according to the left:

   ```
   formatter: function() {
   if (this.point.labelPosition.alignment === 'left') {
     return "<b>" + this.point.name + "</b><br><i style='float: right'>" + "" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 0, ".", " ") + " </i> <i style='float: right'>(" + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y / 11999 * 100), 2, ".", " ") + "%)</i><br><i style='float: right'>" + "" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.z, 0, ".", " ") + " </i>";
   } else {
     return "<b>" + this.point.name + "</b><br><i>" + "" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 0, ".", " ") + " </i> <i>(" + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y / 11999 * 100), 2, ".", " ") + "%)</i><br><i>" + "" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.z, 0, ".", " ") + " </i>";
   }
   }
   ```

Feel free to improve the code. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2vt7394m/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.useHTML

Comment: Thanks for that, it's exactly what I need. I've a last question about the labels : why no labels are displayed in the upper left quadrant of the chart (above "MIDI PYRENEES") ?

Comment: The logic responsible for avoiding overlapping probably hides them. There is an example with padding set as 0. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rpko2q61/